# Why do I have conflicts in namespacing?

Tags: 8

I'm building a traderbot for drupal and I have problems with the namespacing.
Something is not working or I do not understand it correctly. I looked on several pages and questions but could not understand it.

The start

I runned all code without namespaces. Then it is working well !!!

I included a project called ccxt. In this project there are classes with the same name. They have a class called kraken and I have as well. There classes are in namespace ccxt.

So mine class should be namespaced. Which is very obvious.

As I do call from drush I need to have a own autoloader.

```
function autoloader_traderbot( $class_name ){

  // Because of namespaces $class_name could be string/string therefore only the last string should be taken
  if (($pos = strpos($class_name, '\\')) !== FALSE) { 
    $class_name = substr($class_name, $pos+1); 
    (new log)->add(4,'Class name adjusted. Namespace removed from class path.');

  }

  (new log)->add(4,'Searching for loading class  name  : ' . $class_name );

  $dir_iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(CLASS_DIR);
  $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir_iterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

  foreach ($iterator as $file) {
    if($file->getFilename() == $class_name . ".class.php"){
      (new log)->add(4,'Loading class file name (.class.php) : ' . $class_name . ' in filename ' . $file );
      require_once tb_adjustfilename($file);
    }

    if($file->getFilename() == $class_name . ".php"){
      (new log)->add(4,'Loading class file name (.php): ' . $class_name . ' in filename ' . $file);
      require_once tb_adjustfilename($file);      
    };
  }

}
```

So I add in kraken.class.php

```
namespace traderbot;
```

Then calling this object is working fine.

But then the problems are there

I also get

Error: Class 'traderbot\log' not found in traderbot\kraken->update_ohlc() (line 48 of C:\www\tb\modules\custom\tb\src\exchanges\kraken.class.php) #0                                          [31;40m[1m[error][0m

I checked log.class.php.

This is not namespaced so I add

```
namespace traderbot;
```

But then I get from php

```
Error: Class &#039;traderbot\SplFileInfo&#039; not found in traderbot\log->add() (line 66 of C:\www\tb\modules\custom\tb\src\library\log.class.php).
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.
```

But now I'm lost. Because this is just a normal php object so why is it going wrong?

### Addition

Thxs, with the help of the answers it is working now. I saw the excellent video, change the statements, disable my own autoloading procedure.

As a result of this I should add in my classes the use statement for every object I use. The only thing I find a little bit strange is the following.

In every php file with a class I should add the use statement for every object.

Example 1.

```
// Define namespaces and objects
namespace Drupal\tb\library;
use SplFileInfo;
class log{
}
```

Example 2

```
namespace Drupal\tb;

use Drupal\tb\library\log;
use Drupal\tb\datacollector\datacollector;
use Drupal\tb\datacalculator\datacalculator;
use Drupal\tb\scenario\scenario;

class traderbot{


    public function start(){

        (new log)->add(0,"Start data collector");
        $collector = new datacollector;
        ...

        (new log)->add(0,"Start data calculator");
        $indicators = new datacalculator;
        ...

        (new log)->add(0,"Start scenario handler");
        $sc_handler = new scenario;
        ...

    }

}
```

I red some other documentation and QA and understand dat wild card loading of namespacing is not possible. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29851099/how-to-load-all-classes-of-a-namespace
but I also red somewhere that as long as the class is in the same namespace it is not needed to put the use statement for this object. So then I come to the following questions for verification:

Q1) Adding a standard use statement for SPL looks very strange for me. Is this correct?

Q2) Adding a long list of several use statements from unique objects in the same namespace is very strange for me as well. Is this correct?

Comment: Please show us the following to be able to debug your issue: the error, the namespace declaration and class declaration, the code that is calling that class, and any use statements implemented in the file for the code calling that class.

Comment: The namespacing is wrong. Read about PSR-4 autoloading and the doc pages on the same topic in Drupal.

Comment: I still don’t understand why you need to do all of that code like that. Once you properly define your class, you should be able to add a `use ...` statement in the drush command to pull in the class and use it. Read the documentation on drupal.org about creating modules and classes, like a simple FormBase form or Controller. It’s all on display there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This is not namespaced so I add
>
> ```
> namespace traderbot;
> ```

Clearly you don't understand the concept of namespaces, so I suggest you watch [this short video](https://youtu.be/aB1VRlQmq1M?t=0m58s).

After watching the video, you should come to the realization that you're telling PHP to open the "traderbot" folder which does not exist.

According the [official Drupal docs on Namespaces](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/coding-standards/namespaces), you need to structure it like this for Drupal:

> ```
> namespace Drupal\<module name>\SubFolder1\SubFolder2;
> ```

**Note:** Since Drupal uses autodiscovery the `\modules\custom` nor `\src` paths are not need to be declared here, since Drupal will automatically look inside of these.

**Note2:** the file name matters, needs to be YourClassName.php (case sensitive).

> Class Drupal\example_module\Foo\Bar in namespace
>   Drupal\example_module\Foo should be in a file named
>   example_module/src/Foo/Bar.php

so you should remove the `.class` part from your file names. In Drupal the convention is to create a file for each class.

In /modules/custom/tb/src/library/**log.php** you need to put:

```
namespace Drupal\tb\library;
```

Then on /modules/custom/tb/src/exchanges/**kraken.php** to load a class that is in a different name space, you need to put at the top

```
use <name_space>\<class_name>;
```

so it would be:

```
use Drupal\tb\library\log;
```

Comment: Namespaces are effectively class/path mappings for the autoloader and also assist in preventing naming collisions of classes.

Comment: I think the file name also has to be updated to reflect the actual class name as well.