# How do I do namespacing in a module from an external project which is not in the src directory?

Tags: 8

Based on [Why do I have conflicts in namespacing?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/263476/why-do-i-have-conflicts-in-namespacing#comment322774_263476) I adjusted my complete system.

As long as I do namespacing in /src, it is goes all very well.
I included my project from Github. Those class files are located in modules/custom/tb/vendor/ccxt/ccxt/php.

When not working with namespaces I included them with `include "vendor\ccxt\ccxt\ccxt.php";`.

How should I include those classes to module? Because of the Composer structure, those files are in  the vendor sub-directory.

Because of namespacing in Drupal, `use \Drupal\tb\<classfile>` doesn't work.

The content of the composer.json file is the following.

```
    "name": "org/tb",
    "description": "This extension provides new commands for Drush.",
    "type": "drupal-drush",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Author name",
            "email": "author@example.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.0",
        "arcturial/clickatell": "^3.0",
        "ccxt/ccxt": "^1.14"
    },
    "extra": {
        "drush": {
            "services": {
                "drush.services.yml": "^9"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should move the dependency to your project's composer.json rather than having it in your module. Then the autoloading will just work

Comment: Do you have a link with more information about what you are actually saying?

Comment: Just the general Composer/Drupal Composer docs really. All you need to do is remove the vendor folder in your module, go to your project root and run `composer require ccxt/ccxt`, then ccxt's namespaces will be available to your code

Comment: But my project root is ... modules\custom\tb   so it is already there .

Comment: I meant your Drupal project's root

Comment: Very unclear for me what you mean. I now solved it by adding 
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php'; in my module file. Thank you for putting me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 1):

From your post, it looks like you added the above composer.json file, then ran composer from the module root. This is not the way to do it. This will create a vendor folder inside your module folder, which is not what you want.
What you need to do is add the composer.json file to your module, then push that to the remote repository. Then use Composer to install and manage the module. Doing this will add the library to the vendor folder for your project, and the library will be available when calling `\ccxt\ccxt`